# <?php echo nl2br(get_field('内覧はこちら')); ?>にリンクを付けたい

Tags: wordpress

`<?php echo nl2br(get_field('内覧はこちら')); ?>` というコードに、リンクをつけたいです。

上記のコードはwp管理画面のカスタムフィールドへ繋がっており、「投稿」から、「内覧はこちら」というフィールドラベルでURLを入力できるようになっています。

Comment: a タグじゃダメなんでしょうか？

Comment: aタグでは、リンク反映されませんでした＞＜